# FBX from Unity import error

Tags: unity, .fbx

I am exporting FBX file from Unity and try to import it to Blender, some error came and both the transform info and blendshapes were gone.
My Unity version is 2022.3.6f1 and Blender is 4.0.2. I have checked that some models are fine to be imported into Blender, but some are not. That is strange.
Here is the error log:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.0/scripts/addons/io_scene_fbx/__init__.py", line 209, in execute
    if import_fbx.load(self, context, filepath=path, **keywords) == {'FINISHED'}:
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.0/scripts/addons/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py", line 3464, in load
    _(); del _
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.0/scripts/addons/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py", line 3461, in _
    root_helper.link_hierarchy(fbx_tmpl, settings, scene)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.0/scripts/addons/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py", line 2952, in link_hierarchy
    child.link_hierarchy(fbx_tmpl, settings, scene)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.0/scripts/addons/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py", line 2945, in link_hierarchy
    child_obj = child.link_hierarchy(fbx_tmpl, settings, scene)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.0/scripts/addons/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py", line 2908, in link_hierarchy
    (mmat, amat) = mesh.armature_setup[self]
KeyError: Armature
```

If more info is needed, I will post it asap.